# Updating changes while the cluster is running

Tags: java, mongodb, memory, apache-storm

I am using Apache Storm to process log data.

I need to process the log on the basis of IP.I have a list of IP which I need to ignore.Basically, If that particular IP is present then I need to reject the log else process it.

Now , I have stored the IP list in mongoDB ,every time i query mongodb and check whether the IP is present or not.Though it works but it makes the processing slow.

I also tried to store the IP list in memory which made the processing fast but the problem is the list of IP can change.I mean i may need to include or exclude certain IP from the list when the topology is running.

How to solve this? Is there anyway to update the IP's while the cluster is running if there are any changes made in the mongodb(in reference to addition or deletion of the IP) ?

**I cannot use any other DB except mongo to store the IP list.**

Is there any way to trigger an event if the IP list is modified. And refresh the cache.

How to do it in efficient way ?

Comment: There have been a couple of variations on this same question posted by yourself and inevitably removed and re-posted again (presumably either due to the accumulated close votes, and/or since no-one has anwered). In different variations the same thing is asked over and over again, with the same basic answer. "Caching". Close votes given to date are because the question in either specifically "too broad" in the possible solutions to cover, or just outright "Primarily opionion based" with "Vote for Redis, tick box A" or "Vote for MongoDB, tick box B".

Comment: So try to word the question in "terms of your contraints **only**. If you are not "allowed" to set an an external cache, the basically understand that asking a service "out of band" from your application will **always** mean an external hit of some sort. Mongo/Redis/Memcached or whatever will all mean this if running on a separate instance to your application. Your problem could also do with more explaination. Why do you need this? What types of queries are running? Do you can something be "pre-aggregating" results.

Comment: I deleted the previous question because it was not stating the complete problem (Sorry for that). Since, it would have  created confusion if I had edited the question since it already had some answers and suggestion.

Comment: As Also mentioned here previous "question**s**" in the **plural** have been noted. You really need to **1.** Narrrow this down to an exact singular function you want to optimize and explain the usage of the data. **2.** Pick a technology you want answers from and "stick to it". Ask different questions of each technology if you want to get a cross section of information to compare. So, **still way to broad**. Narrow it down to something that can be reasonably answered if you want some real advice. My **advice** here is already more detailed that the question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.Will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by placing an event in `Apache Kafka` every time when I add or remove an IP from the `mongoDB`.  I created a second spout in my topology that listens for those events and sends them along to my bolt.  My bolt would then listen to messages as normal for filtering purposes but also listen for these blacklist events(IPs to ignore) to in order to update its in-memory blacklist state.

I used the ALL grouping for the blacklist events to ensure that all of my bolt instances get the memo that the blacklist has changed.